# Reply to bot from web API

Tags: c#, rest, botframework

In short, I'm trying to resume a conversation with a bot after a successful web API login. But I'm having trouble sending a reply to the bot. I have the `ChannedId` as well as the `UserId`. I'm not sure whether this is enough. I'm also not sure how to construct a new `ConversationReference`, which from my understanding is required to perform the reply (`Conversation.ResumeAsync`)

I have looked at the following example: [MicrosoftDX/AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot), but the example uses `ResumptionCookie` which is deprecated. Furthermore, the example utilizes Azure AD authentication. I use cookie authentication in my web API

I require a response from my web API to continue the login form flow on the bot.

```
    var conversationReference = ???;
    // Create the message that is send to conversation to resume the login flow
    var message = conversationReference.GetPostToUserMessage();
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
    {
        var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
        var sc = scope.Resolve<IStateClient>();
        await Conversation.ResumeAsync(conversationReference, message);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp it may be better for what you are doing.